# How can I generate QR Codes from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been playing around trying to generate QR Codes from a string without any luck. I'm using CodeIgniter. I've tried 2 different packages from Packagist, bacon/bacon-qr-code, and endroid/qrcode. Below is the code in my controller for Bacon :

```
$renderer = new \BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png();
        $renderer->setHeight(256);
        $renderer->setWidth(256);
        $writer = new \BaconQrCode\Writer($renderer);
        $writer->writeFile('Hello World!', 'qrcode.png');
```

When I run this code I get the error 'The phpass class file was not found'.
So I then installed phpass through spark, and I still get the same error.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First one is working as well (probably second one too). 
You need to use it this way (at least):

`APPPATH . 'libraries/Qrcode.php'`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png;
use \BaconQrCode\Writer;

class Qrcode
{
    public function test()
    {
        $renderer = new Png();

        $renderer->setHeight(256);
        $renderer->setWidth(256);
        $writer = new Writer($renderer);
        $writer->writeFile('Hello World!', 'qrcode.png');
        //var_dump($writer);
    }
}
```

`APPPATH . 'controllers/Test.php'`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->qrcode();
    }

    public function qrcode()
    {
        $this->load->library('qrcode');

        $this->qrcode->test();
    }
}
```

And image will be generated in `FCPATH . 'qrcode.png'` file.

Comment: Looks like currently the `Png()` does not exist. I [can't find it](https://github.com/Bacon/BaconQrCode/tree/master/src/Renderer/Image).

Comment: @Pathros This answer is more than 5 years old. You are looking at version 2 of package. In version 1 there is still such a class.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate QR Codes of string using [Google QR Codes API.](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?csw=1#overview)

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=Hello+world&choe=UTF-8
```

- **300x300** is your image size.
- **chl** - a url encoded string to convert it into qr code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had seen this while reading around stackoverflow, but some people were commenting that Google were stopping this service in 2015. I will keep trying, but still unable to make it work!!

Comment: did you read that? `Warning:This API is deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy.`